# capturing the style property top's value change using Jquery

Tags: jquery-ui

In my we page i am dynamically changing the top value for a div's style ie.

<div id="div1" style="top:89;">Test </div>

What i need is to capture the event using Jquery while top value is changed to 88 or 90?

Answer (score 0):

There is no event that is generated when you change the style of an element, so this is impossible.

If you change the style of the element yourself using jQuery, you can of course generate some event there.

Comment: Actually what i need, is to control flexscroll in my web page. I had already customized except scrolling. To get control its scroll need to capture a event while the height value of div changes. Do you have any other Idea? So i could complete the stuff... Than

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not really sure what you mean. Could you provide some sample code in your question?